# SQL Server refuses to connect

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, model-view-controller, reporting-services

I've created a report project in vs and when I deploy it in server it works properly. But I need to embed the reports to an ASP.NET MVC project. So I did this through iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://desktop-8rrbdia:8083/ReportServer" width="1100" height="500" 
        allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe`
```

It shows the list of reports, but when I request particular of them it shows the **8rrbdia refused to connect** error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Please check if the SQL server  service is opened

Comment: It's turned on.